# Javascript tabs: call event onclick

Tags: c#, asp.net, javascript, events

I got some code I need to change. it is build by others, and not very neat...

There is a javascript tabcontrol, containing 4 tabs, which contains gridviews.
All the 4 gridviews are build during the load of the page, but I want them to load, when you activate the tabs (as it is possible to watch the side, while you don't need the specific gridviews to see)

So, my question is: how to call an event (that loads the gridview) from an javascript tab?

how the tabs are generated: (generated code, I know, horrible)

```
var obj = 0;
var oid = 0;
var otb = 0;
var myTabs = new Array();
var myTabitems = new Array();
var myTabitem = new Array();
var myTabContent = new Array();
var myLists = new Array();
```

function showTabContent(tab)
{
    tb = tab.obj;
    id = tab.nr;
    if (myTabs[tb].oid != -1)
    {
        myTabs[tb].myTabContent[myTabs[tb].oid].style.display = 'none';
        myTabs[tb].myTabitem[myTabs[tb].oid].className -= " active";
    }
    myTabs[tb].myTabContent[id].style.display = 'block';
    myTabs[tb].myTabitem[id].className += " active";
    myTabs[tb].oid = id;
}

function boTabs()
{
    var myBlocks = new Array();
    myBlocks = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
    var stopit = myBlocks.length;
    for (var g = 0; g < stopit; g++)
    {
        if (myBlocks[g].className == "tabs")
        {
            myTabs.push(myBlocks[g]);
        }
    }
    var stopit2 = myTabs.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < stopit2; i++)
    {
        myTabs[i].myLists = myTabs[i].getElementsByTagName("ul");
        if (myTabs[i].myLists[0].className == "tabs")
        {
            myTabs[i].myTabitems = myTabs[i].myLists[0].getElementsByTagName("li");
        }
        var stopit3 = myTabs[i].myTabitems.length;
        myTabs[i].obj = i;
        myTabs[i].myTabitem = new Array();
        myTabs[i].myTabContent = new Array();
        for (var j = 0; j < stopit3; j++)
        {
            myTabs[i].myTabitem.push(myTabs[i].myTabitems[j]);
            myTabs[i].myTabitem[j].nr = j; myTabs[i].myTabitem[j].obj = i;
            myTabs[i].myTabitem[j].onclick = function() { showTabContent(this); };
        }
        var myTabDivs = myTabs[i].getElementsByTagName("div");
        for (var j = 0; j < myTabDivs.length; j++)
        {
            if (myTabDivs[j].className == "tabcontent")
            {
                myTabs[i].myTabContent.push(myTabDivs[j]);

`} 
    }
    myTabs[i].myTabitem[0].className += " active";
    myTabs[i].myTabContent[0].style.display = 'block';
    myTabs[i].oid = 0;
    myTabDivs = null;
}
myBlocks = null;`

}
onload = boTabs;

Answer (score 0):

I would change it entirely to use [JQuery Tabs](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Tabs) and [JQuery AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/) to load the grids

Answer (score 0):

If you want a JS solution, you have to build the gridview table yourself using JS code... If you want the server to do the work, you need an UpdatePanel, and make use of the client _doPostBack method.  If you like this approach, the Ajax Control Toolkit tab container can be configured to postback to the server whenever the tab changes, which you can wrap this control with an update panel, and it looks like everything is being done with JS code.  Alternatively, you can also use a web service that binds a gridview and returns the HTML too... not tried that yet, but seen it done.

HTH, if you let me know what option you prefer, I could update accordingly.

Comment: Well, the gridview is bound at the code behind (c#), so it won't be build with JS... I managed to make the tabcontrol with Jquery and CSS. I'll post it as an answer below...
at this moment all 4 gridviews are bound at Page_Load, but, as it takes time to run te sproc's behind the gridview, it takes a few seconds. Therefore I want to load them on tabclick... The UpdatePanel seems the best way...

Comment: Yes, it is very handy; and you can store in a hidden field the selected index of the tab, to know which grid to load.

Answer (score 0):

I now got the tabcontrol made by JQuery and CSS.
at this moment all 4 gridviews are bound at Page_Load, but, as it takes time to run te sproc's behind the gridview, it takes a few seconds. Therefore I want to load them on tabclick... The UpdatePanel seems the best way...

JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{

    //When page loads...
    $(".tab_content").hide(); //Hide all content
    $("ul.tabs li:first").addClass("active").show(); //Activate first tab
    $(".tab_content:first").show(); //Show first tab content

    //On Click Event
    $("ul.tabs li").click(function()
    {

        $("ul.tabs li").removeClass("active"); //Remove any "active" class
        $(this).addClass("active"); //Add "active" class to selected tab
        $(".tab_content").hide(); //Hide all tab content

        var activeTab = $(this).find("a").attr("href"); //Find the href attribute value to identify the active tab + content
        $(activeTab).fadeIn(); //Fade in the active ID content
        return false;
    });
});
```